How do I render a link caption on an o_model child item in a Scriban template?
We have a Rendering Variant that includes a Scriban template where we are iterating through the o_model.children_items like this:
<ul>
    {{for page in o_model.children_items}}
    <li>
        <a href="{{page.link_url}}">{{page.link_text}}</a>
    </li>
    {{end}}
</ul>

This works to pull in the correct link text from the page from the 'Title' field (via page.link_text). However, where we want to have a separate link text in the navigation from the title of the item, we are not sure how to access the correct property name under the page item. Beyond this documentation on o_model, I have been unable to find how to access the specific properties within it.
Is there any further documentation on o_model available? I found this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xc-10-tip-3-scriban-omodel-serge-van-den-oever/, but it is specific to Commerce, and doesn't describe how to get properties for the page of children items.
We have tried to add a new scriban item member processor like this:
public class GetLinkCaption : GetScribanItemMember
{
    protected readonly IContext context;

    protected override string MemberName
    {
        get
        {
            return "link_caption";
        }
    }

    public GetLinkCaption(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override void Resolve(GetScribanItemMembersPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Mode == MemberMode.Name)
        {
            args.Members.Add(this.MemberName);
            return;
        }
        if (args.Item == null)
        {
            args.MemberValue = "#";
            return;
        }
        args.MemberValue = args.Item["Link caption"];
    }
}

with configuration similar to this:
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <getScribanItemMembers>
      <processor type="Sxa102.GetLinkCaption, Sxa102" resolve="true" />
    </getScribanItemMembers>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>

but page.link_caption (for the page item that is one of children items) still does not work.
We can use i_page.link_caption to get the link caption for the current item, but this is not what we want. If we iterate through o_model.list_items like this:
{{ for i_listitem in (o_model.list_items) }}

and then access the property as:
{{ i_listitem.data_item.link_caption }}

you can also get the link caption, but we want to iterate through children items, not list items.
page.data_item is null if we iterate through o_model.children_items as per this:
{{for page in o_model.children_items}}  


Do you mean that you want to pull the link text from a separate field in the "page" item?

Yes, for example, we may want have an external link in the navigation. The external link item does not have a Title in the template upon which it is based, but it does have a "Link caption" field. I want to render the "Link caption" as the link text, when I am iterating through the child items to produce the navigation.

have you tried using {{ sc_field page 'FieldName' }}? It should work for you
